# Passing a class property name to a sub to search a collection

Tags: vba, excel, collections

I have a collection of objects of the same class with a bunch of properties. I want to create a smaller collection that only contains the objects with a certain value for a specific property, and I want to be able to call the sub multiple times for different properties without making lots of versions of the sub.

Here is the section of code which is relevant to the problem:

```
Sub MAIN()

    Dim SplitArr(1 to 2) As Variant
    SplitArr(1) = Y 'where Y is the value you are looking for
    GetSplit arr:=SplitArr, X:=?? 'where ?? is the property you are looking at"

End Sub

Sub GetSplit(ByRef arr(), X as ??) 'unsure what type X should be
    Dim collSplit As Collection
    Set collSplit = New Collection
    For Each v In coll
        If v.X = arr(1) Then
            collSplit.Add v
        End If
    Next v
    Set arr(2) = collSplit
End Sub
```

So what should happen is GetSplit searches through the main collection, coll, and if any of the objects there have the X property equal to Y it will add the object to the collection collSplit. At the end arr(2) is set to collSplit.

The bit I'm not sure how to do is passing a property name to the sub, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would 'variant' work it would allow numbers and strings.

Comment: @ScottCraner I assume Variant is the right type for the sub but I don't know what to set `??` equal to in the sub MAIN() or if my notation will work with `v.X` in GetSplit because X would just be a variable, not a reference to the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example...

clsTest:

```
Public Prop1
Public Prop2
Public Prop3
```

regular module:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim o, i
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim colF As Collection

    'populate some sample data...
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set o = New clsTest
        o.Prop1 = i
        o.Prop2 = i * 5
        o.Prop3 = "Test"
        col.Add o
    Next i

    Set colF = PropFilter(col, "Prop1", 2)
    Debug.Print colF.Count '>> 1

    Set colF = PropFilter(col, "Prop3", "Test")
    Debug.Print colF.Count '>> 10

End Sub


Function PropFilter(col As Collection, propName As String, propValue)
    Dim o
    Dim rv As New Collection
    For Each o In col
        If CallByName(o, propName, VbGet) = propValue Then
            rv.Add o
        End If
    Next o
    Set PropFilter = rv
End Function
```